# Difference between ISAKMP exchanges types IKE_SA_INIT and Identity protection

Tags: ipsec, wireshark, isakmp

I have some `Wireshark` traces to see how ISAKMP works. This traces were taken from peers when a IPsec tunnel is stablished. 
It seems that the traces display a different IPsec implementation. When IKE phase 1 takes place sometimes i see packets marked as `IKE_SA_INIT` and `IKE_AUTH` for the exchange type field of the ISAKMP protocol and sometimes i see packets with the value `Identity protection` and `Quick Mode` for the exchange type field. What is the difference between this implementations of the IKE phase 1?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These packets are from different IKE versions. The packets marked as `IKE_SA_INIT` and `IKE_AUTH` are IKEv2 messages, according to [RFC 7296](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7296). The others are IKEv1 messages ([RFC 2409](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2409) and others). Also, Quick Mode is known as Phase 2, and in IKEv2 there are not really two distinct phases.